# filter array by integers by property of another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,1]
var array2 = [{id:1,name:"test"},{id:2,name:"test2"},{id:3,name:"test2"}]
```

I want to filter array1 by the id property of array2 , so that , the result of array1 should be :

```
array1 = [4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestion:** Please try before ask

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,1]
const array2 = [{id:1,name:"test"},{id:2,name:"test2"},{id:3,name:"test2"}]

const result = array1.filter(i => !array2.find(x => x.id === i))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Next time please try, else no one will answer.